# How to mock a method in Java for testing

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spy, junit-jupiter

I have a class A which has a `methodA` calling a `methodB` in class B.

In class B `methodB` is calling `methodC` in class C.

Class C implements `methodC`.

I am trying to test `methodA` in class A using junit, mockito.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ClassATest {

    @Mock
    APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent event;

    @Mock
    Context context;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    ClassB classB;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    ClassA classA;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("everything should pass")
    public void testMethodA() throws Exception {
 
        Person p = new Person("xyz", "abc", 12345, true);
        when(classB.methodB(any(Molecule.class), eq("abc"), eq(12345), eq(null))).thenReturn(p);


        Map<String, String> headerMap = new HashMap<>();
        headerMap.put("id", "12345");
        when(event.getHeaders()).thenReturn(headerMap);
        when(event.getBody()).thenReturn("{name:hello}");
        assertEquals(classA.methodA(event, context).getStatusCode(), 500);
 
    }
```

I am getting an error of null pointer exception for class C `methodC`. Do I need to mock that as well? Is there a way I can mock `methodB` so that the test does reply on the implementation in `methodB`? As my aim is to test `methodA`, I am fine mocking other methods.

Comment: I would think really really hard if you REALLY need to use Mockito. Most of the cases that I've seen online can be made testable by using the correct architecture and decomposing large services with the help of interfaces. Could you share why you think Mockito is necessary in your case? Is it a 3rd party library you're trying to test that you don't have access to?

Comment: No, I am doing unit test for individual tests, so want to only test a small block at a time. Since I will be testing MethodC separately, I did not want to include it here

Comment: If this is a unit test, then I would strongly advise against using Mockito. It tends to get very messy, and people end up only testing their mocks instead of the actual functionality. May I suggest you watch the following short video that gets my point across: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVjTMOVHgVU

And my point is: think of your class as a set of inputs and a single output, what happens inside is a black box that test should know about. If you provide a known input and know what to expect - that is a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

You are not mocking `ClassB`, you are using the real implementation:

```java
@Spy
@InjectMocks
ClassB classB;
```

If you want to mock it, you need to remove those two annotations and have `@Mock` instead:

```java
@Mock
ClassB classB;
```